# django model inheritance: How does model creation work with custom manager?

Tags: python, django

Recently I've faced an issue with Django, model inheritance and how the creation of model instances works.
Suppose I have the following (basic) setup:

```py
class InviteBaseManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self):
        new_code = # create some kind of unique code, not really relevant here.
        return super().create(code=new_code)

class InviteBase(models.Model):
   code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
   creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

   objects = InviteBaseManager()

class PartyInviteManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, name):
        # method 1
        newInvite = InviteBase.objects.create()
        print(newInvite.code) # is definitly set, lets assume "ABCD" 
        # as expexted, the "InviteBase" table has one row with code "ABCD" and
        # default creationDate
        newPartyInvite = super().create(partyName=name, invite=newInvite)
        print(newPartyInvite.invite.code) # is EMPTY, prints nothing
        # In fact, when looking at the db, there is still only *one* row in the table "InviteBase",
        # with an *empty* code field and a default creationDate field.
        return newPartyInvite


        #method 2
        newPartyInvite = super().create(partyName=name)
        # creates the InviteBase instance implicitly, again, newPartyInvite.invite.code is empty.
        # fill newPartyInvite.invity.code manually.
        return newPartyInvite

class PartyInvite(InviteBase):
   #Isn't blank=False and null=False unnecessary? A child should probably not exist with no parent?
   invite = models.OneToOneField(InviteBase, parent_link=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
   partyName = models.CharField(...)

   objects = PartyInviteManager()
```

So the question is: How can I pass an already existing instance of the base class inside the `create` method of my `PartyInviteManager`? Even when using method 1, the *existing* instance that I pass along seems to be overwritten. A new one is created with the default value. Interestingly enough, this violates the constraints that `code` cannot be blank or `NULL`.

This behaviour seems a bit odd to me? Can someone point out what I am missing here?

To clarify: I know that I should usually use `**kwargs` in the `create` methods and that inheritance might not be the ideal use case here, but I'm just very curious about this behaviour.
I know that this kind of model inheritance  wont even create a `pk` for the child model (because holding a `OneToOneField` to the parent class effectively acts as a `pk` anyway), but why would it be impossible to pass a manually created instance as parent? Am I not allowed to use inheritance for my use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the correct way of doing this:

```py
class InviteBaseManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['code'] = #createCode
        return super().create(**kwargs)

class InviteBase(models.Model):
   code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
   creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

   objects = InviteBaseManager()

class PartyInviteManager(InviteBaseManager):
    def create(self, name):
        return = super().create(partyName=name)

class PartyInvite(InviteBase):
   invite = models.OneToOneField(InviteBase, parent_link=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
   partyName = models.CharField(...)

   objects = PartyInviteManager()
```

The `PartyInviteManager` now inherits from the `InviteManager` as well. When calling `super.create()` from the child manager, the base manager gets called, appends the `code` field and everything works as expected.
I also found out, that if the `PartyInviteManager` does *not* inherit from the `InviteBaseManager`, the `create` method of `InviteBaseManager` does not get called when creating a new `PartyInvite`. This seems very odd to me.

Of course, the easier way would have been to create the code as default value via a function, like that:

```py
def createCode():
   return "ABCD" # add fancy code creation magic here.

class InviteBase:
    code = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False, default=createCode)
```

But if, depending on the child class, the code needs additional information (such as invited members or whatever), this approach would not work anymore.

On a side note, interestingly enough the following code snippet:

```py
invite = PartyInviteManager.objects.create(partyName='Birthday')
print(invite.invite.code)
print(invite.code)
```

produces the following output:

```
ABCD
ABCD
```

In the `create` method of the `PartyInviteManager`, one can directly use `code=XXXX` to pass along a string for the `InviteBase` model, `invite_code` on the other hand does *not* work.